# Check last login of CiviCRM users

Tags: wordpress, civimember, civicrm-home

I am using CiviCRM in WordPress. I just need to know how to check last logged in CiviCRM's user details.

Any helpful response will be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this one got a downvote so bumping in to neutral - people often think that their users can log into CiviCRM

Answer (score 1):

That's more a CMS question - for Wordpress check this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-show-users-last-login-date-in-wordpress/

Users log in using the CMS that is attached to CiviCRM: Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, Backdrop (not CiviCRM itself).

Answer (score 0):

As Karin stated, not every CiviCRM contact is a user of your website. So the latest login is not so much something that CiviCRM is concerned with, but your CMS (Content Management System) which in your case is Wordpress. You should be able to see the latest login there?